# <f:loadBundle basename Non-serializable attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, icefaces-1.8

I'm implementing the Serializable on all my session classes so I could make some farm clustering with a load balancer.

I already have the clustering under control and it's working fine. However, I'm getting an error which it seems I'm not able to solve.

Whenever I enter on the index.jsp I receive this error:

```
Mensaje: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /WEB-INF/inc-content/content.jspx @5,73 <f:loadBundle basename="#{idioma.messageBundleSinProp}"> /WEB-INF/inc-content/content.jspx @5,73 basename="#{idioma.messageBundleSinProp}" setAttribute: Atributo no serializable 
Tipo Error: class javax.servlet.ServletException 
Excepcion: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /WEB-INF/inc-content/content.jspx @5,73 <f:loadBundle basename="#{idioma.messageBundleSinProp}"> /WEB-INF/inc-content/content.jspx @5,73 basename="#{idioma.messageBundleSinProp}" setAttribute: Atributo no serializable 
Codigo de Estado: 500 
Nombre Servlet: jsp
```

Despite the Spanish, it basically says that the attribute isn't serializable. It seems I'm missing something because the `idioma.messageBundleSinProp` is a getter, not a setter:

```
public String getMessageBundle()
{
    if(idiomaSeleccionado!=null)
        return(webUtil.getPropertiesValue(idiomaSeleccionado, "LanguageChances.properties"));
    else
        return(webUtil.getPropertiesValue(idiomaSeleccionadoDefecto, "LanguageChances.properties"));
}

public String getMessageBundleSinProp()
{
    //String propertieSeleccionado=getMessageBundle();
    return(getMessageBundle().substring(0,getMessageBundle().indexOf(".")));
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the loadBundle component was made transient from JSF 2.0.

[Source Code JSF 1.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-impl/1.2_04-p02/com/sun/faces/taglib/jsf_core/LoadBundleTag.java)

[Source Code JSF 2.0](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/faces/taglib/jsf_core/LoadBundleTag.java.html)

Since you are also not using Icefaces 2.0. You cannot make use of this either.
[ICEFACES JIRA](http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-5268)

So the only way I can think of is creating your own messageBean and retriving the messages.

You can do something like this:

```
public class MessageBean implements Serializable
{

   transient private static ResourceBundle bundle;
   transient private static Map map;

protected static ClassLoader getCurrentClassLoader(Object defaultObject)
{
  ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  if (loader == null)
  {
     loader = defaultObject.getClass().getClassLoader();
  }
  return loader;
}

MessageBean()
{
  bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LanguageChances", java.util.Locale.getDefault(), getCurrentClassLoader(null));
  map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
  while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
      String key = keys.nextElement();
      Object value = bundle.getObject(key);
     map.put(key, value);
  }
}

public Map getMap(){
  return map;
}
}
```

And use something like this on your page to retrieve the messages:

```
<c:forEach items="#{messageBean.map}" var="entry">
  <h:outputText value="#{entry.key}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: We load a MessageBundle for each language we have on the app. So, how could I load the `messageBundleSinProp` ? That one is replaced in runtime with whichever bundle needs to be loaded.

Comment: @Antonio How are you specifying which bundle to load is it via a system property?

Comment: really is a getter from the class `IdomaBean` which basically does: `getMessageBundle().substring(0,getMessageBundle().indexOf("."))`.

The MessageBundle is selected at Login, depending certain parameters such as Country code or browser headers.